# PHP Pear Mail SSL Trouble Connecting

Tags: php, email, ssl, openssl, pear

I am receiving

```
Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: (code: -1, response: )]
```

when I try to send out SMTP email.  I've tried both ssl:// and tls:// with no success.

I've verified that my computer can make such an outgoing connection by using outlook configured with an SMTP account and it was able to succesfully send out with TLS.

I also verified that OpenSSL is enabled on the webserver with phpinfo().  It shows PHP 5.3.15 and there is an openssl section that shows OpenSSL Support: enabled

Relevent code:

```
if($isSSL)
    $host="tls://$host";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);
$opts=array ('host' => $host,
            'debug'=>true,
           'auth' => true,
           'port'=>$port,
           'username' => $username,
           'password' => $password);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',$opts);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
```

any thoughts?

Comment: did you try the SAME smtp account from your computer? many home ISPs block access to external mail servers as a spam prevention measure.

Comment: Yes I used the same smtp username and password in outlook and php. Both outlook and php running on my local workstation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssl://` should work. Please also try port 465.

Use `$mail->getUserInfo()` to get a more detailled error message.

Another problem source could be that your firewall doesn't allow outgoing connections to that port.

Comment: Wow, very strange, port 465 worked just now when i was testing with GMail.  I revised my code: to include that line, but $mail->getUserInfo() returns NULL.  I had confirmed that my firewall wasn't blocking the connection (I could send with port 587 through Outlook).  Thanks for the pointer on the port!

Comment: Wow, very strange. `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587` connects, but doesn't present any certificate information, and closes immediately.